# Display Notification Image in Toast Notification of type Windows 10 in WPF

Tags: c#, uwp, notifications, windows-10

i have recently created a toast notification in my desktop chat application and now my task is to assign a notification icon to this generated notification any suggestions hoe to do??

this is the code i used:

```
var data = $@"<toast>
                <visual>
                    <binding template = ""ToastText02 "">
                        <text id = ""1"" > {notif.Title} < /text> 
                        <text id = ""2"" > {notif.Message} < /text> 
                    </binding> 
                </visual> 
             </toast>";

var toastXml = new XmlDocument();
toastXml.LoadXml(data);
var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
toast.Activated += (sender, args) => NavigateUserToConversation(messageDto);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(AppConstants.APP_ID).Show(toast);
```

i tried this line in XMl area:

```
<image placement="appLogoOverride" hint-crop="circle" src="https://picsum.photos/48?image=883"/>
```

and this too:

```
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02);

            // Fill in the text elements
            XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(notif.Title));
            stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(notif.Message));

            //// Specify the absolute path to an image
            XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "pack://application:,,,/Images/BtrackAppIcon.png");
            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
```

while using the second case there is no text displaying but it says a new notification

still no luck

any suggestion on how to implement it

Ihave Created a shortcut in start menu too using code below is there any way to add an image to shortcut explicitly (not in solution properties):

```
private bool TryCreateShortcut()
    {
        String shortcutPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\"+AppConstants.APP_ID+".lnk";
        if (!File.Exists(shortcutPath))
        {
            InstallShortcut(shortcutPath);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void InstallShortcut(String shortcutPath)
    {
        // Find the path to the current executable
        String exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        IShellLinkW newShortcut = (IShellLinkW)new CShellLink();

        // Create a shortcut to the exe
        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetPath(exePath));
        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetArguments(""));

        // Open the shortcut property store, set the AppUserModelId property
        IPropertyStore newShortcutProperties = (IPropertyStore)newShortcut;

        using (PropVariant appId = new PropVariant(AppConstants.APP_ID))
        {
            ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.SetValue(SystemProperties.System.AppUserModel.ID, appId));
            ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.Commit());
        }

        // Commit the shortcut to disk
        IPersistFile newShortcutSave = (IPersistFile)newShortcut;

        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutSave.Save(shortcutPath, true));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I made wrong is That there is a previous version(1.0) of my application installed in my PC so when the notification arrives to my new running application(2.0), since there is already an instance and shortcut created in start menu it is showing a default icon

So once i tried to uninstall the previous version of my application then notification icon appears as it is been set.

Thank You For Your Co-Operation and valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this Microsoft sample. [windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.createtoastnotifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.createtoastnotifier)

For UWP:

```
var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;

// Get the toast notification manager for the current app.
var notificationManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager;

// The getTemplateContent method returns a Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument object
// that contains the toast notification XML content.
var template = notifications.toastTemplateType.toastImageAndText01;
var toastXml = notificationManager.getTemplateContent(notifications.ToastTemplateType[template]);

// You can use the methods from the XML document to specify the required elements for the toast.
var images = toastXml.getElementsByTagName("image");
images[0].setAttribute("src", "images/toastImageAndText.png");

var textNodes = toastXml.getElementsByTagName("text");
textNodes.forEach(function (value, index) {
    var textNumber = index + 1;
    var text = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        text += "Text input " + /*@static_cast(String)*/textNumber + " ";
    }
    value.appendChild(toastXml.createTextNode(text));
});

// Create a toast notification from the XML, then create a ToastNotifier object
// to send the toast.
var toast = new notifications.ToastNotification(toastXml);

notificationManager.createToastNotifier().show(toast);
```

UPDATE :for the Windows 10

```
// Get a toast XML template
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);

// Fill in the text elements
XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
for (int i = 0; i < stringElements.Length; i++)
{
    stringElements[i].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Line " + i));
}

// Specify the absolute path to an image
String imagePath = "file:///" + Path.GetFullPath("toastImageAndText.png");
XmlNodeList imageElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");

ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
```

Comment: imageElements[0].setAttribute("src",imagePath); 
missing i think , add this and try ..

Comment: yep if added that line its not showing any info related to messages received it is saying that a new notification is received from my application with no image in my notification generated